# Books with similar coverage to Linear Algebra Done Wrong

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Axler's book is great, but for my immediate purposes, it isn't suitable. I've been looking at [the Table of Contents of *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* by Treil starting at p. 5 of this document](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong) but there's only one disadvantage to it: I hate learning from reading .pdfs online, and I'd rather not print the entire thing.

Are there books out there (that are published) that have a similar coverage to *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*? There aren't specific topics that I'm looking for in this book - I need **all of them**, essentially (there could be more of a discussion on generalized inverses and pseudoinverses, though).

Comment: Treil's book covers pretty standard topics for an upper division undergrad book from what I can tell of the TOC (well, the last chapter or two cover topics that are often saved until a grad course).  So any book at that level should do.  Why exactly does Axler's book not suit your purpose?

Comment: @Bye_World I'm in a statistics program, and we do a lot of work with matrices (decompositions, determinants, and the like). From what I recall of Axler, little (if any) coverage is done on this.

Comment: Check out Searle's [*Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics*](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470009616/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) and see if it's what you're looking for.  Edit: Actually any of the books mentioned [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/reference-book-for-linear-algebra-applied-to-statistics) might work for you.

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see that question before.

Answer (score 4):

No need to compromise: the Creative Commons license permits printing.  There are many print-on-demand companies that can produce a single copy for you at a very reasonable price.

Comment: You can write this as comment.