# A Proof for Gram-Schmidt Procedure in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I am reading the following proof in the book *Linear Algebra Done Right*. But I don't understand what induction on $j$ means here! I suppose the author means induction on $m$. However, all the proof is talking about $j$ and I don't think this is a typo!

Does induction on $j$ makes sense, here? I mean what is the variable of induction? I am confused!

**My Thought**

What is the index $j$ that the author is talking about in the proof? Is it the same as mentioned in the theorem? If the author is assuming that the theorem is true for $v_1,...,v_k, 1 \le k \le j$ and then wants to prove it for $v_1,...,v_j,v_{j+1}$ while $j$ remain in $1 \le j \le m-1$, then the proof suffers from abuse of notation so badly.

Induction on $j$ seems meaningless to me! Because theorem is an expression which depends on $m$ (the length of the list of linearly independent vectors) not $j$! In other words, we want to see that **Theorem** is true for all $m \ge 2$ or not!

$1$- If I was going to prove the theorem by myself then I would change the last line of theorem by

$$\text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)=\text{span}(e_1,...,e_m)$$

and then do an induction on $m$.

$2$- I also think that we can prove the theorem by induction on $m$ in the original form. It is stronger than the case $1$ above?

[image]

Comment: There's no typo. In this context, $m$ is a parameter, and the construction of an orthonormal basis from s system of linearly independent vectors is a (finite) recursive procedure.

Comment: The induction is on $j$ where $1\le j\le m$. As you rightly observe though, the the condition of finiteness is unnecessary, so that, for example, this procedure applies to Hilbert Spaces also.

Comment: @Bernard: So the induction is on $j$ or $m$?

Comment: It's on $j$ indeed.

Comment: @Bernard: I still think it does not make sense to say induction is on $j$! Did you read the theorem and proof carefully? Maybe I am getting myself confused! It should be on $m$!

Comment: For me it's a fine proof. It says you start with one unit vector $e_1$. Then you construct a second unit vector $e_2$, orthogonal to the first. The again, you construct a third unit vector $e_3$, orthogonal to the first two. The induction part consists in showing that, as long as you do not have an orthonormal list of length $m$, you can continue the procedure. What does not make sense in this?

Comment: @Bernard: Would you please take a look at the lines I added to the question.

Comment: I see. To prove the theorem, you have to prove that for all $j$, the span of $(v_1,\dots,v_j)$ is the same as the span of $(e_1, \dots, e_j)$. This is stronger than your conclusion.

Comment: @Bernard: OK, I got it. :) Many thanks. Would you please write an answer so that I can accept it. Also, the question does not remain unanswered. :)

Comment: @SheldonAxler: I think this proof severely suffers from bad notation as it confused me so badly! :) Can you help me? :)

Comment: @Chilango: What is the index $j$ that the author is talking about in the proof? Is it the same as mentioned in the theorem? If the author is assuming that the theorem is true for $v_1,...,v_k, 1 \le k \le j$ and then wants to prove it for $v_1,...,v_j,v_{j+1}$ while $j$ remain in $1 \le j \le m-1$, then the proof suffers from abuse of notation so badly. Also, proving that $<e_j,e_k>=0$ is not correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the proof in the book is correct; in fact, the statement is exactly what we wanted: $\text{span}(v_1)=\text{span}(e_1)$, $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)=\text{span}(e_1,e_2)$, $\text{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)=\text{span}(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, and go on in general for an infinite list: $\text{span}(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,\ldots)=\text{span}(e_1,e_2,e_3,\ldots,e_n,\ldots)$. Note we need this for the proof of $6.37$ on page 186 of the book:

> $6.37$ Upper-triangular matrix with respect to orthonormal basis
>
> Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. If $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of V, then $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some orthonormal basis of $V$.
>
> **Proof**
>
> ……Because
>
> $\text{span}(e_1,\ldots,e_j)=\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$
>
> for each $j$ (see $6.31$), we conclude that $\text{span}(e_1,\ldots,e_j)$ is invariant under $T$ for each $j=1,\ldots,n$. Thus, by $5.26$, $T$ has an upper triangular matrix with respect to the orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$.

The proof of $6.31$ has no problem. The following visualization should clarify the confusion:

[image]

Or just write out the first few steps explicitly:

$j=1$:

$\text{span}(v_1)=\text{span}(e_1)$ is simple;

$j=2$:

We have $v_2\notin\text{span}(v_1)$.

Let $1\leq k<2$, so $k=1$.

$\displaystyle\langle e_2,e_1\rangle=\frac{\langle v_2, e_1\rangle-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle}{\|v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1\|}=0$, so $e_1,e_2$ are orthonormal. From the picture above, it is clear that $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)=\text{span}(e_1,e_2)$.

$j=3$:

We have $v_3\notin\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$.

$\displaystyle e_3=\frac{v_3-\langle v_3, e_1\rangle e_1-\langle v_3,e_2\rangle e_2}{\|v_3-\langle v_3, e_1\rangle e_1-\langle v_3,e_2\rangle e_2\|}$

Let $1\leq k<3$, so $k=1,2$.

$\displaystyle\langle e_3,e_1\rangle=\frac{\langle v_3,e_1\rangle-\langle v_3,e_1\rangle-\langle v_3,e_2\rangle\cdot0}{\|\cdots\|}=0$

$\displaystyle\langle e_3,e_2\rangle=\frac{\langle v_3,e_2\rangle-\langle v_3,e_1\rangle\cdot0-\langle v_3,e_2\rangle}{\|\cdots\|}=0$

So $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are orthonormal.

$\vdots$

When things go too abstract in this book, it is often helpful to draw some pictures, play with $2\times 2$ matrices, or resort to other less "theoretical" books. By the way, I like this book very much.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the attention. I know what Gram-Schmidt is about and what it means but I have problem with the induction argument in the proof. Also, I have seen many proofs for Gram-Schmidt but this really is the worst as it confuses me so badly! :) Also, no motivation is given for the formula! This is one of the worst proofs that Axler has written in his nice book! :)

Comment: Also in $(6.32)$, $j$ should be replaced with $k$ and $m$ with $j$. I mean it should be for $1 \le k \le j$ we have verified that  $\text{span}(v_1,...,v_{k-1})=\text{span}(e_1,...,e_{k-1})$

Comment: @H.R. I don't think so….it is most straightforward to think the case for infinite list of vectors $(v_1,v_2,\ldots)$, so please drop the $m$, or let $m=\infty$! The $k$ is also of limited use: it is only a convenient name for the previous vectors $e_1, e_2,\ldots$.

Comment: But I think so! :) If you write down the induction hypothesis once by $j$ denoting the length of linearly independent list you will get me. Anyway, thanks for the answer.  :) Also I may thanks Sheldon for his bad writing which causes me to think more! :)

Comment: @H.R. so the proof really goes like: suppose the theorem holds for $1,2,\ldots,j-1$, then we prove it for $j$. The proof is indeed a little terse with lots of $m,j,k$ cracked in; we should never care them too much. A picture or a few more steps is helpful, but the book is for extreme beauty, as we can seen elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah. ;) Agreed! :) and thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Have you read the entire book? If *yes*, then it will be useful to add some review in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472978/is-linear-algebra-done-right-3rd-edition-good-for-a-beginner). :)

Comment: I did the review. Welcome to have a look.