# Proof of Gram-Schmidt process using strong induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, orthogonality

The Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of a linearly independent set $S=\lbrace v_1,v_2,\dots,v_p \rbrace$-- assuming finite-ness for convenience-- is given by $u_1=v_1$ and $k>1\implies u_k=v_k-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\langle v_k,u_i \rangle u_i /\lvert u_i \rvert^2$.

Many of the proofs I've seen of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization have been quite confusing, save perhaps for [this here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894001/a-proof-for-gram-schmidt-procedure-in-linear-algebra-done-right). I liked the proof in [this document](http://galileo.math.siu.edu/Courses/221/Sum08/Handouts/gramschmidt.pdf), but was confused by the inductive hypothesis on page 3. The author assumes that $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{k-2}$ are all orthogonal to $u_{k-1}$, then sets out to prove that the $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{k-2}$ are also all orthogonal to $u_k$. That seems fine; however, in the inductive step, they further assume that all of the $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{k-2}$ are *mutually* orthogonal, which (to my knowledge) wasn't stated in the inductive hypothesis.

Below is my attempt at a proof using strong induction.

---

Define a predicate $\varphi(k)$ in one variable $k\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots,p\right\} $
as follows:
$$
\varphi(k)=\forall(m<k).\left\langle u_{m},u_{k}\right\rangle = 0.
$$
In words, $\varphi(k)$ means that $u_{k}$ is orthogonal to each
preceeding $u_{m}$. Clearly we have $\varphi(1)$, since $m\nless1$
for $m\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots,p\right\} $; and we have also $\varphi(2)$
since $u_{1}\perp u_{2}$; as well as $\varphi(3)$, since $u_{1}\perp u_{3}$ and $u_{2}\perp u_{3}$.

**Claim:** We have $\varphi(j)$ for all $j\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots,p\right\} =: I$.
Equivalently, we have $u_{i}\perp u_{j}$ for all $i\neq j$ in $I$.

*Proof:*
As stated above, we already have $\varphi(1)$, $\varphi(2)$ and $\varphi(3)$.
Now suppose there is some $j\in I$ such that $\varphi(k)$ holds
for all $k<j$ in $I$. That is, for all $k<j$ and all $m<k$, we
have that $\left\langle u_{m},u_{k}\right\rangle =0.$ Now consider
$\left\langle u_{m},u_{j}\right\rangle $ for $m<k<j$. Letting $J:=\left\{ 1,2,\dots,j\right\} $, so that $J\setminus\left\{ j,m\right\} =\left\{ 1,2,\dots,m-1,m+1,\dots,j-1\right\}$, we
have
\begin{align*}
\left\langle u_{m},u_{j}\right\rangle = & \left\langle u_{m},v_{j}-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{\left\langle v_{j},u_{i}\right\rangle }{\left|u_{i}\right|^{2}}u_{i}\right\rangle =\left\langle u_{m},v_{j}\right\rangle -\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{\left\langle v_{j},u_{i}\right\rangle \left\langle u_{m},u_{i}\right\rangle }{\left|u_{i}\right|^{2}}\\
= & \left\langle u_{m},v_{j}\right\rangle -\sum_{i\in J\setminus\left\{ j\right\} }\frac{\left\langle v_{j},u_{i}\right\rangle \left\langle u_{m},u_{i}\right\rangle }{\left|u_{i}\right|^{2}}\\
= & \left\langle u_{m},v_{j}\right\rangle -\left\langle v_{j},u_{m}\right\rangle -\sum_{i\in J\setminus\left\{ j,m\right\} }\frac{\left\langle v_{j},u_{i}\right\rangle \left\langle u_{m},u_{i}\right\rangle }{\left|u_{i}\right|^{2}}\\
= & -\sum_{i\in J\setminus\left\{ j,m\right\} }\frac{\left\langle v_{j},u_{i}\right\rangle \left\langle u_{m},u_{i}\right\rangle }{\left|u_{i}\right|^{2}}
\end{align*}
but inside the sum we have $i\leq j-1\implies i<j$, so $\left\langle u_{m},u_{i}\right\rangle =0$
by our inductive hypothesis. We therefore get $\left\langle u_{m},u_{j}\right\rangle =0$.

We've just shown that $\left[\forall(k<j).\varphi(k)\right]\implies\varphi(j)$.
By the principle of (complete/strong) mathematical induction, we have
that $\varphi(j)$ holds for all $j\in I$, and so $u_{i}\perp u_{j}$
for all $i\neq j$ in $I$.

---

I'd appreciate if anyone could assuage my woes over the first proof mentioned above, as well as verify the proof I've provided. Also, I know that it's possible to use double induction to first prove that $\langle u_1, u_i \rangle = 0$ and then prove that $\langle u_i,u_j \rangle = 0$, similar to the proof of commutativity of multiplication on $\mathbb{N}$, but I'm not sure how to tackle the second induction there.

Comment: If you use strong induction then you don't need nothing more. The strong induction here is to say that $u_j$ for $j=1,\dots,k-2$ are mutually orthogonal to $u_{k-1}$ and your induction proof is to show that $u_{k-1}$ is orthogonal to $u_k$. This whole conundrum works because in the basis step you show that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are _mutually_ orthogonal.