# is Linear Algebra Done Right too much for a beginner?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am self studying the book *Linear Algebra Done Right*. That's how I start using this great Stack Exchange in Mathematics!

I do not have a background in mathematics and just finished my undergraduate and want to learn Maths.

I try to read every page and finish all exercise (Now on Chapter 3: Linear Maps). And on average, it takes me an hour to finish a page (exercise included). I can finsih 1/3, if not 1/4 of the questions on my own. For the rest, I need to look at the solutions to get some hints. Sometime, I don't even understand the solutions......

Just want to know if I am too slow on average? Are the questions hard for beginners on average (Not IQ above 160 type)? (Just tell me the truth, I will keep going and finish the book even if you tell me the questions are super easy.)

I know that there is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472978/is-linear-algebra-done-right-3rd-edition-good-for-a-beginner). But I want more info on the average pace, and difficulty of questions.

Comment: "It takes me an hour to finish a page."  That's pretty normal if you are new to a subject.  Take your time.

Comment: Linear algebra comes very easy to some and not to others.  Being experienced with examples of linear transformations in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ can be helpful.  I had trouble understanding linear algebra very well until after I took several courses in abstract algebra (which did come naturally to me).

Comment: @Displayname That's quite funny. But can very easily become depressing if you can back it up with data and/or sources. Can you?

Comment: If you're not enjoying Linear Algebra Done Right, why not try [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html)?

Comment: You might also check out my linear algebra lectures on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). The course includes multivariable calculus/analysis as well, but the linear algebra material might be more accessible to you than some texts. (In particular, my approach is more geometric. If you hate that, perhaps it won't be your cup of tea.)

Comment: @Displayname Unfortunately your comment strikes me as complete and utter nonsense.

Comment: @T.Bongers : I would interpret it like Git Gud, as a joke

Comment: @Displayname how long does it take you to watch rick and morty tho?

Comment: Yes, the questions are hard for beginners. Linear Algebra Done Right might be particularly difficult for beginners who are not already comfortable with proofs. You could try looking at some other books also, such as Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra, or Friedman, Insel, and Spence.

Comment: @Timkinsella I'm an undergrad I can't comprehend it, I'll give it a watch in a couple years when my IQ increases

Comment: A) you are definitely not too slow. B) every single person gets better after practice. C) the time you need for exercises depends on your background knowledge & mental well being (e.g. if you are motivated you learn better, if you believe in yourself you learn better, if you got enough positivity you learn better, if you have a nice environment to learn you learn better, ...) D) IQ measures how good you are in certain types of activities measured in an IQ test and with propper training you get better in it, it does not measure how good you are in linear algebra so it seems irrelevant to me

Comment: @Max Then perhaps this isn't the best place to BS someone who is asking an honest question. This edginess about IQ is rather off-putting to me, even if it's intended as a joke.

Comment: @D_S Whether it comes fast or slow has to do with your general math knowledge at the time of commencing the topic, the handbook you use, how sceptical you are about the material (e.g. spending or not spending time on looking whether the given statements were true and looking for proofs...), ...

Comment: Please consider also asking this on Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange. They'll probably have further thoughts about the learning process and how to judge the appropriateness the book.